# __doPostBack when trying to impelent a Logout button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Actually i'm new in Vb.Net and ASPX and i'm trying to add to my website a logout button but when i'm clicking it it doesn't work and giving me the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM45:1
```

Here is my <'a'> tag to which i'm trying to add the logout method:

```
                <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="ExitBtn" runat="server">
                                   <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                   <p>Esci</p>
                            </a>
                </li>
```

While here is codebehind:

```
Protected Sub ExitBtn_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitBtn.ServerClick
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Response.Redirect("auth.aspx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it inside a form tag. If it doesn't work, please post the whole page codes.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="ExitBtn" runat="server">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Esci</p>
   </a>
  </li>
</form>
```